# Exe created out of bat file using iexpress fails to execute

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd, iexpress

I have a batch file invoking the "sqlcmd" drop and create procedure commands, it works fine on executing just the bat file. But when the .bat file is converted executable using iexpress(Windows tool), the application fails to run with the below mentioned error.

I tried converting "bat file executing sql script for the Database creation" into exe using iexpress and it worked fine. But drop and create procedure commands are failing.

Am trying create an exe from batch file, using iexpress tool. During package all the dependendency files are included into the package. My issue is in creating the exe from "CreateProcedure.bat". Suggestions and solutions are appreciated.

CreateDB.bat

```
set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client 
SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;%path%
sqlcmd -U sa -P texas#2019 -i CreateDB.sql
```

CreateDB.sql

```
GO
CREATE DATABASE TEX
ON
( NAME = TEX_Data,
  FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEX_Data.MDF',
  SIZE = 500,
  MAXSIZE = 500, 
  FILEGROWTH = 0 )
LOG ON
( NAME = TEX_Log,
  FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEX_Log.LDF',
  SIZE = 250,
  MAXSIZE = 250, 
  FILEGROWTH = 0 )
GO
USE TEX
GO
CREATE LOGIN texas WITH PASSWORD = 'texas',CHECK_POLICY = OFF
GO
USE TEX
GO
sp_adduser 'texas'
GRANT 
 BACKUP DATABASE,
 BACKUP LOG,
 CREATE DEFAULT,
 CREATE FUNCTION,
 CREATE PROCEDURE,
 CREATE RULE,
 CREATE TABLE,
 CREATE VIEW 
 TO iris; 
ALTER DATABASE TKO SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
```

CreateProcedure.bat

```
USE master
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop table staging"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_old"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_from_old"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_export"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_no_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_4_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_no_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_4_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_export_no_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_export_4_TEX"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_4"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_4"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_5"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_5"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_4_TEX_Rel_5"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_4_TEX_Rel_5"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_6"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_6"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_import_4_TEX_Rel_6"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -Q "drop procedure sp_staging_4_TEX_Rel_6"
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_old.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_from_old.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_no_TEX.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_4.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_5.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_6.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_no_TEX_Rel_7.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_4_TEX.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_4_TEX_Rel_5.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_4_TEX_Rel_6.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_import_4_TEX_Rel_7.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_4.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_5.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_6.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_no_TEX_Rel_7.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_no_TEX.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_4_TEX.sql
sqlcmd -U texas -P texas -d TEX -i sp_staging_4_TEX_Rel_5.sql
```

### Error:

```
"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not 
have the appropriate permissions to access the item"

Also the following notification from antivirus program:
"A Process was blocked because malicious behaviour was detected"
```

Comment: Why are you using batch files to do this? You would likely be better off using PoSh (you probably won't get the message from your antivirus then). As for the other error, it's telling you the problem; the user account can't access the directory you're trying to access.

Comment: Obviously, the anti-virus program blocked the IExpress processes. Solutions include what @Larnu suggested, disabling anti-virus, or excluding the folder from anti-virus.

Comment: it's legacy design and not suppose to change now. The intention of converting to exe is to hide the database login credentials, without modifying the source code or design.

I feel the error message is pointing incorrect reason, because "CreateDB.bat" and "CreateDB.sql" are working fine( No error message nor the process is blocked). "CreateProcedure.bat" is also similar but more set commands to sqlcmd utility.

Based on my requirement is there any different approach, to achieve above mentioned.?

What is Posh?

@Larnu Thank you for response.

Comment: PoSh=PowerShell.

Comment: Okay, I tried converting to PoSh but still the same issue.

Comment: Disable your virus-scan while you run the exe. Or tell the virus-scan that file is safe. If you're getting malicious code blocked errors, this is exactly the problem. Furthermore, making it an EXE wont hide that password from people that really want it. All you need is a memory editor to get it. Not too secure.